# How to keep the title and favicon of my website when it is redirected?

Tags: html, redirect, iframe, dns, favicon

I created a website that I am hosting at a local server and I bought a domain at one.com that I am redirecting to the IP address of my server using web DNS.

When I put the IP address in the browser everything works fine. However, when I type the name of my domain, the website is loaded but the title and favicon are not displayed.

Inspecting the source code in the browser I realized that my index.html is injected into the body of a new html document using iframe, which includes a new head element with a different title and without the favicon. I have tried with no success to dynamically change the title using javascript as:

```
<script>
   document.title = "my title";
</script>
```

I have also tried to delay this function using setTimeout() with the same result. I am a noob, so this might be something very trivial but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this server have a static external IP address?

Comment: Yes, the server has a static IP address.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to not use "redirecting through web DNS", but point your DNS record directly to your static IP address.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what the difference between redirecting through web DNS and pointing my DNS is, could you please elaborate on that? Also, I am not sure how to implement it, since I am using the seemingly limited options provided by the site where I bought my domain name...

Comment: It depends indeed on the options this provider provides. Pointing a DNS record to an IP requires access to an environment (provided by provider) to set such a thing. It sounds like `window.parent.document.title = 'title'` is your only option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is executed within an iframe. To access the parent, you should be able to use:

```
window.parent.document.title = "A damn good title"
```

**update**

Due to the fact that main document and iframe are not from the same origin, and the CORS headers can't be set, the above won't work.

Apparently the *cheap* DNS provider does not allow you to configure the entries (that would have allowed you to point the domain name directly to your IP address), the only option remaining is to move to a better provider.

Comment: I tried that and got the following error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "IP address" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Ah yeah, CORS... That will be hard to fix if you don't control the original host. Any chance your DNS provider has some documentation?

Comment: First thing I did was to try to contact their support service but all I got from them was: "sorry, there's nothing we can do about it". Hence, here I am...

Comment: That's quite disappointing, but I guess there's not much you can do in that case.